# How to build program in Go subdirectory?

Tags: go

I have directory structure below. So server.go is in the main dir , and client.go in client sub directory (both are in package main). When I do ' go get -u ...' I have only server.go compiled under the name of MyGoProgram which is fine (executable in $GOPATH/bin)

```
MyGoProgram
client/client.go
server.go
```

How do I compile client.go ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to match your go directory to the structure described here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

so you should have:

```
{$GOPATH}/bin
         /pkg
         /src/MyGoProgram/server.go
                         /client/client.go
```

cd to `{$GOPATH}` and run the command `go install ./src/MyGoProgram`
the executable will be created at `/bin/MyGoProgram.exe`

Comment: so in fact go install ./src/MyGoProgram/client , thnx it worked

Comment: I think this advice is out of date with the new go modules structure.  The referenced path https://golang.org/doc/code.html still works, but there's nothing there about pkg and src directories.